# Getting Error 500 with this .htaccess on Linux, works fine on Windows

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, lamp

I'm using XAMPP on Windows and LAMPP on Linux (Ubuntu) to develop in PHP locally. I have this in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

As you can see I don't want to type the extensions of filenames that end with either HTML or PHP. My both `.htaccess` contains same above content.

Amazingly, when I am requesting any file (or directory) on Ubuntu (even if with full extension), I'm getting `Error 500`. If I remove this `.htaccess`, everything gets well.

Everything is working as expected on Windows.

What's the problem?

Comment: what does error log said? Try to enable rewrite rule log to debug it :)

Comment: @rkosegi How to enable rewrite rule log?

Comment: @rkosegi There is a log file named `error_log` at `/opt/lampp/logs/`. The last line is: `[Thu Sep 06 20:14:25 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /opt/lampp/htdocs/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`. But I still didn't understand why don't Windows have any problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The last line is: 
>   `[Thu Sep 06 20:14:25 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] /opt/lampp/htdocs/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfRewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

Those characters (`\xef\xbb\xbf`) are the [unicode byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) for UTF-8 and apache thinks it's garbage characters (on linux at least). In windows, this BOM is used to let Windows know that the file is encoded as UTF-8 instead of whatever default windows text file uses (I think it's UTF-16, little endian). You just need to go use your favorite linux text editor, and delete those characters. Depending on what editor you use, they may not even show up, so you may need to do something like "select from the end of the word `RewriteEngine` to the beginning of the line, and delete selection, then, from the beginning of the line, just type `RewriteEngine` by hand.

There's a chance that the htaccess file won't work properly once you move it back to Windows after removing the BOM, I'm not really sure.

Comment: I knew about BOM already, but didn't knew that it can create this type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

I also opened .htaccess in notepad and got error 500.

I dont know if my solution will work for you but I just copied all from .htaccess and then deleted the old .htaccess and created a new one and pasted the data back and it worked.

Comment: wow, Thanks a bilion. This one worked for me.