# .htaccess mod_rewrite 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I succeeded to use .htaccess with mod_rewrite for my first domain name.

I try to use it for a second domaine name, and I have for result "Internal Server Error".

However, I put the same files on their server, and they have the same configuration.

The content of the .htaccess file :

```
﻿Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Where can the problem come from ?

Best regards,

Comment: The rule you posted looks ok. Check your server error log to know the reason of 500 error.

Comment: www/.htaccess: Invalid command '\xef\xbb\xbfOptions', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it's a problem with the encodage.

[Getting Error 500 with this .htaccess on Linux, works fine on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12299684/getting-error-500-with-this-htaccess-on-linux-works-fine-on-windows)